# How can Read txt file from sd list when file is clicked? Android

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am trying to make an application that displays a `list` of `.txt`-files that are in a specified folder on the sd-card. When the user selects a file, I want the app to open it and read its content.

Is there a way of only displaying files with extension `.txt` on my `list`?

This is the code I'm using to open the file and read the text when the user selects a file:

```
public class TxtView extends ListActivity {

private File currentDir;
private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    currentDir = new File("/sdcard/Txt");
    fill(currentDir);
}

private void fill(File f)
{
    File[]dirs = f.listFiles();
     this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());

     List<Option>dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
     List<Option>fls = new ArrayList<Option>();
     try{
         for(File ff: dirs)
         {
            if(ff.isDirectory())
                dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"Folder",ff.getAbsolutePath()));
            else
            {
                fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(),"File Size: "+ff.length(),ff.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
         }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {

     }
     Collections.sort(dir);
     Collections.sort(fls);
     dir.addAll(fls);
     if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Txt"))
         dir.add(0,new Option("..","Parent Directory",f.getParent()));
     adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(TxtView.this,R.layout.file_view,dir);
     this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Option o = adapter.getItem(position);
    if(o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder")||o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
            currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use a ListView or GridView to display all of file options. In either case, you can use an ArrayAdapter or extend BaseAdapter, which are used for containing data that populates your View. I am not going to post all the code because it is  a lot, but [here is an example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). With respect to getting the files you want, assuming your location is sdcard/yourdir than:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourdir/";
File f = new File(path);
ArrayList<String> allTxtFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
try{
  for(File tmp : files.listFiles() ){
    if(tmp.toString().matches(".*\\.txt"))
        allTextFiles.add(path+tmp.toString());
  }
}catch{
}
```

You probably don't want to use that exact code, but should get you to where you need to get.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start practicing with what you have given me, to see what I can get, and forgiveness until now I could edit the code, my internet was disconnected. Thanks for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working on android,
1 - Read all the files in a directory with filter to only allow .txt files
2 - Show the list on ListView
3 - On click, send Absolute file path to your text file reader function

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've been able to show the list of files, but I can not implement the filter. I dont Know  where I cant put the filter, I edit the code that was up, that's how I have the code now. Thanks